# drawing a line from the center of a circle to the outter arc given a degree

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js

***CORRECTED***

***This is actually not down to the maths it was ll down to the lines array and SegandSubSegCount. Basically I was trying to draw more lines than I needed.***

I have a circle that is dynamically split into sectors (depending on data that comes in dictates the number of sectors) These sectors are then grouped into sections (this is worked out earlier and when looping to draw the sections i have an array that contains a 1 or 0 to state if a line needs to be drawn (lines[] contains this information))

The code i have works in some cases but not in others and I cannot see why. I have been at this for a few days now and I am just up against a brick wall.

The code i have is as follows

```
/*var SegandSubSegCount is calculated from a loop and is just the total number of sectors and sections. 

For example there could be 9 sub sectors and 3 sections (3 sectors in each section - in this instance the below code renders the section lines correctly) 

or there could be  13 sub sectors and 4 sections (3 sections have 4 sectors and 1 has 1 sector - in this instance the below code does not render correctly)*/

    var segment =  360 / SegandSubSegCount;
    var segmentWidth = rad / _config.Levels;
    var spindleStartPoint = segmentWidth*2;
    var rad = _config.Radius;

    function xycoord(angle) {
                    return {
                        //convert the angle passed to a radian
                        x: (rad+30) * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180),
                        y: (rad + 30) * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180)
                    };
                }

            //this is used to move the inner radius of where to draw the segment line from so it does not draw from the middle of the circle
                function innerxycoord(angle) {
                    return {
                        //convert the angle passed to a radian
                        x: spindleStartPoint * Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180),
                        y: spindleStartPoint * Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180)
                    };
                }

                for (var t = 0; t < SegandSubSegCount; t++) {
                    //lines dictates if a line needs to be draw the show a section
                    if (lines[t] === 1) {                    
                        var angle = segment * t;
                        var inner = innerxycoord(angle);
                        var tip = xycoord(angle);
                        coords.push({ x1: inner.x, y1: inner.y, x2: tip.x, y2: tip.y, colour: "white", width: 0.5, opacity: 0.5 });
                    }
                }
```

in the instances where it works the lines are drawing in the correct palces (as seen by sector lines drawn under it and the section lines line up correctly)

when it does not work the section lines math up with 0 degree but then are off for all other sector lines.

Below is an image of when it is not working

[image: Example of when it is not working]

Comment: Are you looking for a [radar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/6506614)?

Comment: Can you show us the angles of each of the lines you circled? And the coordinates returned by `xycoord` for each of those angles?

Comment: hey thanks for the comments. I managed to get this corrected though. It was nothing todo with the maths it was all down to the lines array and SegandSubSegCount. Basically I was trying to draw more lines than i needed